# Boost Spirit: Feedback from parsing - replacement for information in parse_info

Tags: parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have implemented a grammer using boost spirit.  It is used for parsing a command line language for issuing commands to a piece of software.  The user types these commands.  The parser is going reasonably well for a small subset of the language.

As the user types the text I would like to give simple feedback to the user before the user hits the enter key to action the command.  For example I would like to change the colour if the command line represents a complete command that parses to completion.  Rather than accept an invalid key when the user hits a key I would like to perhaps beep and not accept the key.

My idea was to submit the command string to the parser with each key press and use feedback from the parse process to establish if a phrase would parse completely or parse completely validly up to the end of the input or alternatively parse with an error.

I did a bit of searching on the web and found that parse_info used to be returned by parse in spirit classic but now parse only returns a bool.  The indicates the successful state but I have no indication for the cases if the input expression parses up to the end of the input but the parser just needs more input.  parse_info seemed to contain all the information I needed.

Can anybody explain a reasonably simple way of finding out this information after parsing an expression.

Thank you very much,
Callum.

Answer (score 2):

The start iterator is passed by reference. So, actually the information is richer: you can always see what amount of the input has been consumed correctly **even** if the parse result is "success" (boolean `true`).

The drill:

```
auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, grammar, qi::space);

if (ok)
    std::cout << "Parse success\n";
else
    std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

if (f!=l)
    std::cout << "Trailing unparsed input: '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I have tried your suggestion but I don't seem to get all the information I need...  If there is insufficient input to complete the rule then pharse_parse returns false and the iterator is left at the start.  If there is enough input to completely define the rule and some extra input then phrase parse returns true and the iterator is advanced to the end of the successfully parsed input.  I can't detect the case of just running out of input from invalid input.  This is what I need.

Comment: @CallumJamieson: You might want to have two grammars then, or modify your grammar so that it accepts any prefix of any other string that it accepts. This might be annoying depending on what your grammar looks like. In most applications of PEG parsers, people don't really want this "any prefix" behavior, they want precise parsing. If you have a grammar element like `qi::lit("init")`, you might have to change it to something like `-('i' >> -('n' >> -('i' >> -'t')))`. You might be able to use a helper function to make these parser elements...

Comment: AFAIK this is a general limitation of spirit -- it doesn't really have 'good', 'bad', 'indeterminate' parsing. For instance, you might look at this example HTTP parser in the boost asio docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/http/server/request_parser.hpp In this code, the parser returns a tristate "good", "bad", "indeterminate", which is important for handling http since the request comes in chunks. I don't know a good way to rewrite that code in spirit for example, since it would have to reparse each time a new piece comes. Would love to know.

Comment: @ChrisBeck You'd need tristate results on _every_ single parser primitive. It sounds like an interesting bit of work, and not unfeasible actually. Perhaps someone is interested in providing it in X3

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and thoughts, much appreciated...  Since this is a reasonably small simple grammer I have implemented my own parser that has these three state results.